# Break out multiple coordinates into multiple latlng googlemap v2

Tags: android, latitude-longitude

I have a huge list in an XML tag like so:

```
<coor>     -123.3858,41.34119,0
     -123.3856,41.34109,0
     -123.3852,41.34121,0
     -123.3848,41.34139,0</coor>
```

and need it like this:

```
           new LatLng(-123.3858,41.34119),
           new LatLng(-123.3856,41.34109),
           new LatLng(-123.3852,41.34121),
           new LatLng(-123.3848,41.34139),
```

to work with google maps v2 android.

I've done a string replace on the coordinates and am getting the correct results like so:

```
String ll = "),new LatLng(";
coor = coor.replaceAll(",0", ll);
```

replacing the ,0 for the new LatLng(... I am not figuring out how to change the large string of latlng text into latlng locations to put into my polygon:

```
PolygonOptions perimeteres = new PolygonOptions().add(coor);
```

Is there way to do this? Or do I need to separate each out and make them individual latlng?

EDIT::::

```
String[] splitData = coor.split(",0");
                    for (String eachSplit : splitData) {
                        if (!eachSplit.endsWith(",0")) {
                            //Log.e("EACH",eachSplit);
                            Log.v("e","new LatLon("+eachSplit+");");
                        }
                    }
```

This is getting me a little closer...

Comment: You need to pass the object LatLng, not a messed up string.. Maybe the API accepts an array of LatLng objects, even so, you would have to instanciate this objects.

Comment: yeah I dont understand why wou are creating strings like objects

Comment: So go through the entire coor tag replace ,0 and add each line to a list? How do I know each coor is unique? Select before the ,0?

Answer (score 0):

You are going completely in the wrong direction, this

```
String ll = "),new LatLng(";
coor = coor.replaceAll(",0", ll);
```

is not the same as

```
new LatLng(-123.3858,41.34119)
```

the first gives you a string which does nothing for you, the second is an object which is what you need.

**Edit**

you need to remove the `0` from the coordinates then you do a string split on the `,` so you have an array of latitudes and longitudes.

then create a `List<LatLng>` which is what you need to create a polygon of points

and loop through your points

```
for(int j=0;j<locationAry.length;j++){
    if(j%2 == 0){
        lon = Float.parseFloat(locationAry[j+1]);
        lat = Float.parseFloat(locationAry[j]);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I understand that... what I need is a way to break out all of those coors into separate latlng. I can always change a string into a double, but want to know how to get all those coors into usable strings first... or latlng if there is a way.

Comment: Awesome, yes, this is more like it. I'll give it a shot.